# How to include JS in text from JS

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, button, interaction

I have a function, ajaxinclude() which includes the content of a page.
It works perfectly when written like:

```
<div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          ajaxinclude("info/content/About.php")
     </script>
</div>
```

Now, I want a button on-click this should come.
Thus,

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('aaa').innerHTML = '<script type='text/javascript'>ajaxinclude(\'info/content/About.php\');</script>">Hello</button>
```

But this doesn't work.

Another method would be

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('aaa').innerHTML = '<script type='text/javascript'>' + ajaxinclude('info/content/About.php') + '</script>">Hello</button>
```

But this doesn't work either.

This is my ajaxinclude() function:

```
var rootdomain = "http://" + window.location.hostname;

function ajaxinclude(url) {
    var page_request = false

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    else if (window.ActiveXObject){
        try {
            page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        } 
        catch (e){
            try{
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            }
            catch (e){}
        }
    }
    else
    return false
    page_request.open('GET', url, false)
    page_request.send(null)
    writecontent(page_request)
}

function writecontent(page_request){
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1 || page_request.status==200)
    document.write(page_request.responseText)
}
```

How, how do I include the text on a button click?

PS: I don't want jQuery.

Comment: what is the element 'aaa'?
You want to get the response text to be written to element 'aaa'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('aaa').innerHTML = ajaxinclude('info/content/About.php')">Hello</button>
```

However I must warn that inline JavaScript is bad practice, especially like this! You can rewrite your `writecontent` function to accept two parameters: the page request and the ID of the target to write to.

Your new `writecontent` function would be:

```
function writecontent(page_request, write_target){
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1 || page_request.status==200) {
        document.getElementById(write_target).innerHTML = page_request.responseText;
    }
}
```

You'll need to pass the ID of the write target there, and since you're calling `writecontent` from `ajaxinclude`, you'll need the parameter there too:

```
function ajaxinclude(url, write_target) {
    // ...
    writecontent(page_request, write_target);
}
```

And in the button:

```
<button onclick="ajaxinclude('info/content/About.php', 'aaa')">Hello</button>
```

### Optionally continuing...

Even better would be binding the `click` action to the button instead of using `onclick`. This would be easier with jQuery, but since you explicitly stated you do not want to use jQuery, you can also do it using `addEventListener()` in your JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('thisbutton').addEventListener('click', function(){ajaxinclude('info/content/About.php', 'aaa')}, false);
```

And that would change the button to:

```
<button id='thisbutton'>Hello</button>
```

[Read more about event listeners at the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

What is you intent .

By your code by clicking the button the innerHTML of element by ID "aaa" becomes script function